# Add a button to MFC CDockingPane titlebar

Tags: c++, mfc

Anyone knows how to add a button to the titlebar of a `CDockablePane` ?  I tried the usual way with `CDialog` but it does not work for `CDockablePane`...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of [CMFCCaptionButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984171.aspx), then use the protected *but undocumented* `m_arrButtons` member of the [CDockablePane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984433.aspx) class:

```
yourDockablePane.m_arrButtons.Add(new CMFCCaptionButton(YOURCOMMANDID));
```

Comment: Two more questions then (not an MFC expert). 1 - Where is in my CDockablePane-Derived class the best place to put the code  2 - Do I need to sublcass the CMMFCCaptionButton to create a custom button (with custom icon) ?

Comment: I found the answer for question one... its in CDockablePanel::SetCaptionButtons override.  Way too obvious, sorry...

Comment: @smichaud, good :) Concerning your second question, you'll have to subclass `CMFCCaptionButton` and override its [OnDraw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc702147.aspx) method.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, thanks.  For a minute there I alsmost thought that there would be a way to just supply to bitmap handles or something of the likes... :(